# SQL Update Multiple Rows with Count from another Table

Tags: sql, count, sql-update, teradata-aster

Suppose I have two tables.  One table, tbl1, is "long" and non-aggregated.  The structure is as follows:

```
Software_Name:
Word
PowerPoint
PowerPoint
Excel
Word
PowerPoint
```

In a second Table, tbl2, I want to summarize the data from the first table, namely the count of Software.  The second Table will have a structure like:

```
Software_Name:      Count:
Word                 2
PowerPoint           3
Excel                1
```

I have tried:

```
update tbl2
set count = 
(select count(software_name)
from tbl1
group by software_name
where tbl1.software_name = tbl2.software_name)
from tbl1
```

I get a result inserted into the proper column, but it is not the proper value.  It is the sum of all values, in this case 5.  I have included the `where` clause because in my tbl1 I have many more software_names than am interested in counting in tbl2.

**UPDATE**
I am using Teradata Aster for this project.  I have been looking at the Aster documentation for the UPDATE command and came across this:

```
UPDATE [ ONLY ] table
   SET column = expression [, ...]
   [ FROM fromlist ]
   [ WHERE condition | WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name ];
```

In reading about the fromlist, I came across this bit of information:

> Note that the target table must not appear in the fromlist unless you intend a
>   self-join (in which case it must appear with an alias in the fromlist).

Comment: Your where is after your group by...I don't know what dbms allows that...but putting it before the group by should solve it

Answer (score 2):

You want a correlated subquery:

```
update tbl2
    set count = (select count(*) from tbl1 where tbl1.software_name = tbl2.software_name);
```

Comment: I like this solution.  Unfortunately, I get a column name does not exist error despite the column being in the table.  Any insights into why that might happen?

Comment: @Daniel . . . There must be a misspelling or something.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't look like a misspelling.  I am using Aster if that makes a difference.  I'm unable to find any documentation that talks about the error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what DBMS you're using but in SQL Server I would recommend a CROSS APPLY with example below...

```
update t2
set t2.[Count] = t1.[Count]
from t2
    cross apply (
                    select count(*) AS [Count]
                    from t1
                    where t1.Software_name = t2.Software_name
                ) AS t1
```

You can read more about the APPLY operator here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the CTE as below:

```
DECLARE @TABLE1 AS TABLE (Software_Name VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @TABLE1
SELECT 'Word'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'PowerPoint'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'PowerPoint'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Excel'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Word'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'PowerPoint'



 DECLARE @TABLE2 AS TABLE (Software_Name VARCHAR(100),Cnt INT)
 INSERT INTO @TABLE2 (Software_Name)
 SELECT DISTINCT Software_Name FROM @TABLE1



 ;WITH CTE AS
 (
     SELECT 
         COUNT(T1.Software_Name) AS Cnt
         ,T1.Software_Name 
     FROM @TABLE2 T2
     INNER JOIN @TABLE1 T1 ON T1.Software_Name = T2.Software_Name
     GROUP BY
     T1.Software_Name
 )


 UPDATE T2
 SET 
 T2.Cnt =  C.Cnt
 FROM @TABLE2 T2
 INNER JOIN CTE C ON C.Software_Name = T2.Software_Name

 SELECT * FROM @TABLE2
```

NOTE: I am assuming you are using SQL Server. Also i am posting it as an answer as i dont have desired reputation to comment.

hope it helps!